# How to convert this php code in a wordpress shortcode?

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

Hi I found this code on online, it is a simple button to reveal the coupon code and open the URL at the same time.

```
function coupon_add($coup, $uurl)
{
echo "    
<script type='text/javascript'>
<!--
function coupon(coup,url) 
{alert('COUPON CODE: ' + coup);
window.open(url,'_blank');
}
//-->
</script>";    
echo "<center><br /><input style=\"width:250px; height:60px;font-
size:30px;\" type=\"button\" onclick=\"coupon('".$coup."','".$uurl."')\" 
value=\"VIEW COUPON\" \/></center><p>";
}
```

I would like to turn this into a short code so I can insert it into a post. Would love some help with this, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

In your functions.php:

```
add_shortcode( 'my_coupon_add', 'sc_my_coupon_add' );
function sc_my_coupon_add( $args, $content = null ){
  $atts = shortcode_atts( array(
    'coup' => '',
    'uurl' => ''
  ), $args, 'my_coupon_add' );
  return "<script type='text/javascript'>
    function coupon( coup, url ){
      alert( 'COUPON CODE: ' + coup );
      window.open( url, '_blank' );
    }
   </script>  
   <center><br /><input style=\"width:250px; height:60px;font-size:30px;\" type=\"button\" onclick=\"coupon('" . $atts[ 'coup' ] . "','" . $atts[ 'uurl' ] . "')\" value=\"VIEW COUPON\" \/></center><p>";
}
```

Now you can use the shortcode `[my_coupon_add coup="" uurl=""]` and pass your parameters. The way the javascript is written, this can only be used once on a page or post or else you'll have issues with the `coupon()` function, but this should give you enough to scale/rewrite it if needed more than once (like moving the `coupon()` javascript function to a main js file so it's available once and only when needed).

You might need to double-check the single and double quotes - I whipped this up quickly.